# Resources for writing a good master's proposal?

Tags: thesis, masters, reference-request, research-proposal

I would like to write and submit a master's thesis proposal next year and do not know where to start.

Does there exist a template or a step-by-step guide to help me get started?

For instance:

> Script how
>
> > 1. Introduction
> > 2. Objectives
> >
> >    > 2.1 Motivation
> > 3. Methodologies
> >
> >    > 3.1 References
> > 4. Research
> > 5. Results
> > 6. Conclusion

I am new to the world of research and am a little lost. Can anybody shed some light on this?

I Already have one subject that would like of write, it would be about 
computer network - bandwidth oriented monitoring

Comment: The best way to write a compelling SOP is to have a compelling purpose. Focus on that, and the statement will wrote itself. What do you tell people when they ask what your research interests are? When they ask you why you’re pursuing the degree?

Comment: If you're planning to write your master's proposal in English, then you're going to need to work on improve your writing skills significantly. I could barely understand what you've written!

Comment: Sorry, My official language is portugues, I am terrible with o english, I am using more at community for to practice  (with help of google translate)